# How to set value to label in jsp page through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, label

This is my label.

```
<label class="control-label " for="no1" id="lbl_count">0</label>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_btn">Add to cart</button>
```

And this is the function I try to set amount of raw in the jsp page to a label. But it is not working. Both label and button not are in same div. But both of them are in same form.

```
   <script>
        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('#submit_btn').click(function() {

                var x = document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length;
                alert(x);
                //    $("label[for='no1']").text(x);
               //     $("#lbl_count").text(x);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I tried several ways non of them are working.. Alert is working. That means data is coming. So how to fix this. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: html snippet please.

Comment: there is a large area. @ NorlihazmeyGhazali What part u actually need

Comment: label and submit button. cause this `$("label[for='no1']").text(x);` should work unless there is something wrong with html part.

Comment: My mistake. I'm sorry

Comment: there is nothing wrong with jQuery code. But, you have `button="submit"`, which mean when clicked on submit button, the alert come out, and after click OK button, the page will refresh. Then, you can't see the changes on label.

Comment: So what should do? I definitely have to use a submit button with a form. Because I have record to save.

Comment: Use ajax instead. Avoid page being refresh after submit button was clicked, then you can change the label after ajax request success.

Comment: I tried to use static variable. It also seems to give false value after dew times refreshing. Is that useful.

Comment: does't matter you used static or dynamic, it this case, you can't see the changes of label because right after submit button was clicked, the page refresh.

Comment: Can you please give me a small ajax example on this. And thank your for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can't see the changes of label because right after submit button was clicked, the page refresh(showing the original state). Try prevent the default event for the element, so then you can see the changes on label.

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //<-add ^this
            var x = document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length;  // use this or try with static value like var x = "23";
            $("#lbl_count").text(x);
        });
    });
</script>
```

But, the form will not submit. As you mention before, having record to save, then use ajax post instead.

**AJAX EXAMPLE**

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <label for="no1" id="lbl_count">0</label>
  <input type="text" name="var1" id="var1"/>
  <button type="submit" id="submit_btn">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
  $('document').ready(function() {
        $('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();               
            $.ajax({
                type : 'post',
                data : 'var1='+$('#var1').val(),
                url : 'your_jsp_process_page.jsp',
                success : function(data){
                    var x = 'hello';
                    $("#lbl_count").text(x);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

**your_jsp_process_page.jsp**
In this page, need to retrieve the value sent from ajax. In this example, retrieve it with name `var1`. Here you can see the data key and value paired `data : 'var1='+$('#var1').val(),`.

Comment: Can u please give me a small example of ajax. I'm really new to this stuff. Please.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) If has any doubt can I ask it again within this hour. Will you please reply back?

Comment: Okey, feel free to ask